# How to define a 2D array with points and limiting x and y separately

Tags: python, numpy

I want to generate a 2D array of points with varying range lengths of x and y like so:

```
points = np.random.uniform(0, 300, (10000, 2))
```

This gives me 10000 points (with x and y) with range from 0 to 300. But I would like to limit the number for x and y separately. I would like x to range from 0 to 1280 and y to range from 0 to 720.

Is numpy capable of doing this, or I'm better off constructing such array by myself?

Comment: What do you imagine such an array to look like?

Comment: For example, where should the numbers 720 < x < 1280 go? What does it mean to separate out the limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
np.random.uniform((0, 0), (1280 ,702), (10000, 2))

array([[1273.36065074,  593.61346294],
       [ 861.09537599,  608.0452186 ],
       [ 931.37010986,  529.71771209],
       ...,
       [ 931.70239685,  442.04459329],
       [ 764.29249852,  396.72112753],
       [ 858.85217637,  437.34670284]])
```

Note that, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html), both the `low` and `high` values accept float or array_like of floats.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I was looking for :)